# Trying to do a MATCH inside of a nested FOREACH list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of nodes with label Type. Some of them have relationships to other Type nodes and some of them do not. I want to loop through all of the Type nodes and do some action based on the relationship (whether it is null or has an existing relationship)

In pseudo code, this is what I want to do:

```
For each type1 in allTypes
     For each type2 in allTypes
        Match relationship between type1 and type2   
        If relationship between type1 and type2 exists
             do something
        else
             do other thing
```

But I can't figure out how to do this in Cypher. I understand you can't do a MATCH inside a FOREACH statement in Cypher, so I'm trying with UNWIND like this:

```
MATCH (Types:Type)
WITH COLLECT(Types) AS types
UNWIND types as type1
UNWIND types as type2
MATCH (type1)-[r]->(type2)
RETURN type1.name,type(r), type2.name
```

This works fine for all the relationships that *already* exist, but when there is no relationship between type1 and type2, I'm not getting anything in my return result.

Comment: What do you want to do if the relation does not yet exist?

Comment: What are the alternative "things" that you plan to do in each case? Are they mutating (i.e., do they alter the graph) or require addiitonal querying at all, or just returning properties from your path?

Comment: I think you may want to let go of the idea of looping, that's for more of an imperative approach, and even if you managed to make that work, it would be inefficient. Your pseudocode uses a double for loop, which would translate to a cartesian product for n^2 complexity. By matching once on all :Types, figuring out what relationships exist to other :Types (or if no such relationship exists) you should have a O(n) operation.

Comment: Thanks guys, I realize that what I was trying to do was not a great design. I'm taking a different approach now. Thanks for the pushes in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `OPTIONAL MATCH`?

Some example data:

```
CREATE 
  (t1:Type {name:"t1"}),
  (t2:Type {name:"t2"}),
  (t3:Type {name:"t3"}),
  (t1)-[:REL]->(t2)
```

The query:

```
MATCH (t1:Type)
OPTIONAL MATCH (t1)-[r]->(t2:Type)
RETURN
  t1, t2,
  CASE r
    WHEN NULL THEN "other thing"
    ELSE "something"
  END AS info
```

The results:

```
╒══════════╤══════════╤═══════════╕
│t1        │t2        │info       │
╞══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│{name: t1}│{name: t2}│something  │
├──────────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│{name: t2}│(null)    │other thing│
├──────────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│{name: t3}│(null)    │other thing│
└──────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: This looks very close, but we're looking for relationships to other :Type nodes, so instead of `(t2)` I think this should be `(t2:Type)`.